# SwiftUI -- More than one Picker in a view

Tags: swiftui, picker

I'm trying to create a view with several independent SwiftUI Pickers. The following code doesn't work as soon as I uncomment the `.pickerStyle(.wheel)` statement. I can not select the first two Pickers, all interactions go to the last one :-(

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection1 = 0
    @State private var selection2 = 0
    @State private var selection3 = 0

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            NumberPickerView(selection: $selection1)
            NumberPickerView(selection: $selection2)
            NumberPickerView(selection: $selection3)
        }
    }
}

struct NumberPickerView: View {
    @Binding var selection : Int
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Number", selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(0..<100) { index in
                Text("\(index)")
            }
        }//.pickerStyle(.wheel)
        .frame(width: 50)
        .clipped()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing some simple detail.

Comment: It is known that it does not work anymore - Apple implicitly prohibited that since, seems, iOS 15.

Comment: Don't think so ...
Changing the `HStack` to a `VStack` and removing the
```
.frame(width: 50)
.clipped()
```
works

Comment: I'm exactly about `.clipped`

Comment: Which you could easily read out of your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is found valid workaround - reconfigure UIPickerView (which is still used internally) to all compress its content (actually that we try to do with .frame).

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
extension UIPickerView {
    override open func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        self.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    }
}
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestMultiPickersInRow.swift)